# CreateFile() returns INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE (C++)

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Consider:

```
void main()
{
    LPSTR FileName;
    FileName = "C:\\test2.wav";
    hFile = CreateFile((LPCWSTR)FileName, GENERIC_READ, 0, 0,
                       OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE, 0);
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        cout << "INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE" << endl;
        return;
    }
}
```

This program always prints "INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE". Why? File `C:\test2.wav` exists.

Comment: Casting a string to a wide string DOESN'T WORK!

Comment: More accurately, casting an `LPSTR` to a `LPWSTR` doesn't work.

Answer (score 8):

You misunderstand how casting works. What you are saying to the compiler is to pretend that FileName is a wide string, but it isn't so your code fails. Two solutions

1) Use the right kind of string (a wide string in your case)

```
LPTSTR FileName;
FileName = _T("c:\\test2.wav");
hFile = CreateFile(FileName, GENERIC_READ, 0 , 0,
    OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE, 0);
```

2) Use the version of CreateFile (called CreateFileA) that requires a narrow string

```
LPSTR FileName;
FileName = "c:\\test2.wav";
hFile = CreateFileA(FileName, GENERIC_READ, 0 , 0,
    OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE, 0);
```

It's a common feature of newbie code that it has casts all over the place. Try to avoid casting as it often just hides errors (like your cast did). This is especially true if you don't understand how casts work. Unfortunately it's not possible to do Windows programming without a certain number of casts.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just cast a multibyte/ASCII/UTF-8 string to a wide/UTF-16 string. You actually have to convert it. Try using [`MultiByteToWideChar()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to convert it. The other answers talking about the different versions of `CreateFile` are probably simplest, but just in case you actually need wide character strings this can be useful to know.